# service accounts configuration in template file in osb 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, osb, oracle-fusion-middleware, oracle-service-bus

I need to configure service accounts for connecting to some of the services and for that we are required to configure the details in a template file. 
So basically that means, I want to configure service account at run time. 
We are using oracle service bus 11g.
Since I've never worked on service accounts before, any suggestions will be helpful.

I checked that we can do that at run time by fn-bea:lookupBasicCredentials XQuery function. but this is not what we want. We want to generated dynamically through the template files.

Comment: Can you explain more about what you mean when you write 'template files' in an OSB11 scenario?

Comment: Do you mean a ws security header?